# Finding size without using sizeof

Tags: c, sizeof

I understand that we can find the size of a pointer of certain type using the following:

```
printf("size of an int pointer: %d", sizeof(int*));
printf("size of a float pointer: %d", sizeof(float*));
printf("size of pointer to void: %d", sizeof(void*));
```

In C, is it possible to find the size of a `struct` without needing to use `sizeof`?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? What's wrong with using `sizeof`?

Comment: @Barmar It's just for educational purposes. There is nothing wrong with `sizeof`. Thanks.

Comment: First of all you should be using `%zu`

Comment: Note that size of a pointer is always same as `sizeof(int*)`, doesn't matter if it's pointer of  `float` or `struct` type.

Comment: @Jack: That happens to be true for most implementations, but it's definitely not guaranteed by the C standard. For example, on a word-addressed system an `int*` might be one word, and a `char*` might require an additional offset to identify the byte within the word.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Thank you very much for the correction. I used to think it isn't implementation-independent. In fact, I remember I've read somewhere that the size of a pointer is always `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, there's a lot of misinformation out there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perform pointer arithmetic and measure the step size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct foo { char a[5],b[98];};

#define SYZEOV(t) ((size_t)((void*)(((t*)(NULL))+1)-NULL))


int main(int m, char**n){
  printf("sizeexpr=%ld\n", (long)((void*)(((struct foo*)(NULL))+1)-NULL));
  printf("syzeov  =%ld\n", (long)SYZEOV(struct foo));
  printf("sizeof  =%ld\n", (long)sizeof(struct foo));
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: Suggest dropping the `(long)` cast and use `"%jd"`.

Comment: @chux on what basis do you reason that ptrdiff_t is the same as intmax_t`

Comment: My mistake, not "%jd" for `intmax_t`, but suggest dropping the (long) cast and use "%td", as a pointer difference is type `ptrdiff_t`.  If system does not support "%td", then cast to `intmax_t` and use "%jd".  IAC - nice answer

Comment: several upvotes for invoking *undefined behaviour* :)

Comment: Nice, can also make a macro for variables:  `sizeof(m)` by using `((void*)(&m+1)-(void*)(&m))` but i can't imagine how `sizeof(1)` could be done.

Comment: @Jasen Hi, which part of it defines "undefined behaviour" to your eyes?

Comment: U.B.  is doing pointer arithmetic on NULL, it's only allowed on allocated (static,  auto, malloc(), alloca() (etc...)) addresses of the apropriate type, which NULL, by definition is not.   OTOH this is done at compile time... so it can't be all that undefined!

Comment: @Jasen Right, thanks. But like the other commenter above, I also can't see how `sizeof(1)` could be done. Would you please clarify that?

Comment: I don't think that it can be done. my expression only works with types, rpattiso has produced one that works with lvalues, but I can't see a way to make it work with generic expressions like `sizeof 1` does  (parentheses are only needed for types)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we could do the following to find the size of a `struct` without using `sizeof`:

```
struct myStruct
{
   int a;
   int b;
}

struct myStruct s = {0, 0};

myStruct *structPointer = &s;
unsigned char *pointer1, *pointer2;
pointer1 = (unsigned char*) structPointer;
pointer2 = (unsigned char*) ++structPointer;

printf("%d", pointer2 - pointer1);
```

Comment: Afaik, that uses sizeof anyway to perform ++structPointer, so why not use it directly? And why ask a question and answer it yourself?

Comment: @user1320881 Because the question specifically asked how to do it without using the `sizeof` operator. Of course it uses the compiler's internal knowledge of the size of the structure.

Comment: pointer2 - pointer1 returns a ptrdiff_t, which is not represented by the %d format string.

Comment: @Barmar Can you please expand more on the "compiler's internal knowledge" part?

Comment: It means that ++structPointer does structPointer += sizeof(MyStruct) internally anyway.

Comment: The compiler has to know the size of the structure so that it knows how much to increase the pointer by when you do `++structPointer`.

Comment: @user1320881 "why ask a question and answer it yourself?" --> [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @user1320881: No, it does not use the `sizeof` operator internally.

Answer (score -1):

In short, you can't. Some people have suggested using pointer arithmetic, like you did in your answer, as well as using macros to make "a sizeof operator." The reason being that sizes of data types are only known by the machine's compiler. Your pointer arithmetic is using the sizeof operator, "behind the scenes".

Comment: No, pointer arithmetic is not using the `sizeof` operator behind the scenes. Both pointer arithmetic and the result of the `sizeof` operator depend on the size of the operand or of the pointed-to object.

Answer (score -1):

C is designed in such a way that `sizeof` always returns the amount of pointer increment in bytes to move to the next array element, so that `sizeof(type[N]) == N*sizeof(type)` is always true.

Then it's your choice to use either.

And then, neither `sizeof` nor pointer increment really returns the size of the operand, instead, they both return the amount of memory occupied per object when they are made an array.

Try something like:

```
struct myStruct
{
   double a;
   char b;
}
```

then `sizeof(struct myStruct)` is very likely to be `2*sizeof(double)`, not `sizeof(double)+sizeof(char)`, because the next array element when you make an array of `myStruct` has to be that far away.

Is `myStruct` really using that much space? Probably not.

if you do something like:

```
struct myBigStruct
{
   struct myStruct small;
   char b;
}
```

then `sizeof(struct myBigStruct)` is very likely to be still `2*sizeof(double)`, not `sizeof(struct myStruct)+sizeof(char)`

All these are implementation dependent.

It's just because too many people assumes `sizeof(type[N]) == N*sizeof(type)` so C forces it to be true by making `sizeof` this way.

Comment: sizeof is not a function, it is not called and it does not "return"  it's a compiler directive